# Is there a place for keeping "problem solving hints"?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that I often collect data to diagnose a problem by:

1. Causing the problem to happen, then
2. `ls -lrt/var/log`,
3. `tail -n 25` on recently modified log files, and
4. `dmesg`.
5. Read, wonder, think, guess, test, repeat as needed.

I'm sure that most of you have a few canned methods (like the above) for gaining information.

Where is a good place to share these tips?

Answer (score 4):

If you can make them somewhat specific to a set of problems, you can ask a question and answer it yourself:

- How do I debug hard drive mounting errors?
- How can I find out what's causing X to crash?

  ...

Here's a prime specimen of such a question:

- [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into)